# VBScript: Error with regex matching incorrect registry values

Tags: java, regex, vbscript, registry

I am trying to match a Java version in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall by iterating over the subkeys within Uninstall. I am trying to match a regular expression to Java 7 Update 40, but the regex is matching all DisplayName entries. Below is the code:

```
 On Error Resume Next 
 Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002 
 Dim oReg 
 Dim objShell

 Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
 Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\.\root\default:StdRegProv") 
 Dim sPath, aSub, sKey 
 Set objRegEx = New RegExp 
 objRegEx.Pattern = "\w{4}\s\d{1}\s\w{6}\s\d+" 
 objRedEx.IgnoreCase = True 
 objRegEx.Global = False


 sPath = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" 
 oReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sPath, aSub 
 For Each sKey In aSub 
 disName = "HKLM" & "\" & sPath & "\" & sKey & "\DisplayName" 
 unString = "HKLM" & "\" & sPath & "\" & sKey & "\UninstallString" 
 reDisName = objShell.RegRead(disName) 
 reUnString = objShell.RegRead(unString) 
 'Wscript.echo(reDisName)

 If objRexEx.Test( reDisName ) Then 
      Wscript.echo "Match" 
 End If

 'Wscript.echo ObjShell.RegRead(disName) 
 'Wscript.echo ObjShell.RegRead(unString) 
 Next
```

Sorry if the formatting is off, I put a ctrl-k in front of each code line. This is my first time posting here so go easy...

Comment: You can indent each line with 5 spaces, makes a code block. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

You should start all your scripts with `Option Explicit` and `Dim` all your variables. Then you wouldn't need sln's eagle eyes to spot your typo:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objRegEx : Set objRegEx = New RegExp
objRegEx.Pattern = "\w{4}\s\d{1}\s\w{6}\s\d+"
objRedEx.IgnoreCase = True
```

output:

```
cscript 19188400.vbs
...\19188400.vbs(4, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Variable is undefined: 'objRedEx'
```

If you insist on using a global `On Error Resume Next` (a most dangerous mal-practice) then you should disable it until your script is thoroughly debugged. Keeping the OERN in a script known to have even the slightest problem is inviting desaster. Asking for help with code containing a global OERN is futile. So run you program without the OERN and see if the cause for its misbehaviour in't obvious.

Diagnostic output should be as specific as possible. Your `WScript.Echo "Match"` just shows that the statement is executed; a `WScript.Echo "Match", disname` would be a bit better. Using .Execute and looking at the Match's details could be more revealing.

The .Pattern should be more specific to. If you look for java updates, anchoring a literal "java" at the start of the string, and asking for "upgrade" instead of "\w{6}" may help to avoid false positives. OTOH, my display names don't look like

```
Java 7 Update 19
```

but like

```
Java(TM) 6 Update 19
```

and who knows what the next owner of Java will put into the display name.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm new to the world of windows coding and just picked it up the other day. I'm way more used to python on linux and that global "on error resume next" was accidentally left in there. Before I started running it with cscript in a terminal window I was using the IDE to execute it and those Wscript.echo errors popping up were driving me nuts. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: That Java (major) Update minor is going to bite me in the ass I bet. This is going to run on a domain with a couple hundred machines on it. All windows 7. I got it working now and it matches correctly and returns the correct uninstall string. My only fear is exactly what you pointed out in that java may be Java(TM) in DisplayName in the registry. This is why I chose linux about 15 years ago. The registry. I am learning a lot with VBScript and actually having fun doing so. It has really made me respect the windows people in the office way more than I used to.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a few typo's

objRe`d`Ex.IgnoreCase = True
...
If objRe`x`Ex.Test( reDisName ) Then

Comment: If changed the RedEx to Regex and it's still the same issue. Plus when iterating the reg values it seems to print certain values several times and still does not match the intended value. My regex should match "Java 7 Update 40" and I've tested that and it does work in a test script. I'm at a loss for words...